# Проверка соединения с сервером в php

Tags: php, mysql, сервер

На сервере имеется хранилище данных (каталог в котором текстовые файлы) к которому с сайта нужно обращаться. Но дело в том, что по тем или иным причинам он бывает недоступен. 
Поэтому надо организовать проверку доступности сервера, чтобы выводилось спустя, допустим, секунд 15 сообщение: "Не могу подключиться к name_server". 
Как организовать такую проверку?

Comment: А вы уверены, что ваш вопрос связан с mysql?

Comment: @DmitriySimushev нет, скорей всего тут вообще без этого можно обойтись. Я видела реализацию с mysql_ping, но понимаю, что скорей всего это не то, что мне нужно и что я пытаюсь сделать.

Comment: Каким образом вы получаете файлы с того сервера? Покажите код. Имя сервера можно заменить на `example.com`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Решила проблем очень простым и не таким уж и надежным способом, но на первое время пусть будет так:**

```
$url = '//mypage/www/html/test_b.ru/www/opr/admin/store/V6/000Admin/history.txt';
// пробуем открыть файл для чтения
if (fopen($url, "r")) {
//echo "<p><font size='3,5' color='black'> <b>Server is available. </b></font></p>";
} else {
echo "<p><font size='3,5' color='black'> <b>Server is not available. </b></font></p>";
}
fclose ($url);
```

**Всем спасибо за помощь.**

Answer (score 0):

Используйте [это](http://php.net/manual/ru/pdo.construct.php), первый же пример поможет. А вообще почитайте [здесь](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.mysql-connect.php) про `mysql_connect`. Знаю человека который уже кучу страниц изза этого переписывал.

Answer (score -1):

```
<?php
$server = 'localhost';
$user = 'dbuser';
$password = 'dbpass';

$dblink = mysql_connect($server, $user, $password);

if($dblink)
echo 'Соединение установлено.';
else
die('Ошибка подключения к серверу баз данных.');

$database = 'dbbase';
$selected = mysql_select_db($database, $dblink);
if($selected)
echo ' Подключение к базе данных прошло успешно.';
else
die(' База данных не найдена или отсутствует доступ.');
?>
```

Подробнее можно прочитать тут http://rtfm.co.ua/php-mysql-proverka-soedineniya-s-serverom-i-podklyucheniya-k-baze/

p.s Может я не правильно вас понял. Ответе в комментариях поправлю ответ.
Поясните что вы имеете ввиду под серверам.

Покажите как вы подключаетесь, скиньте ошибку какую вам выдает если сервер не отвечает

Comment: Спасибо, наверное, я сама от незнания дезинформирую всех. Дело в том, что на сервере просто каталог с файлами (pdb-ешки хранятся). Их можно просматривать или удалять уже устаревшие с сайта. Вот мне скорей всего достаточно первой части (до databese). А лучше реализовать отдельным скриптом или в index.php можно дописать? А можно это сделать как-нибудь через `get_headers`? Допустим, если ответ 200, то ОК, работаем дальше, а если не 200, то сообщение выводить, что облом?

Comment: Блин, только это опять скорей на проверку существования файла, а не просто соединения. С другой стороны, если проверка прошла с положительным статусом, то и сервер доступен. Верно?

Comment: @Юленька, через get_headers можно (мог не правильно вас понять). Сделайте проверку и если ответ  200 то все норм. Создавать отдельный файл или делать все в одном то тут как вам удобнее (строгих правил нет, я бы делал наверное в отдельно но не факт). Второй комментарий не совсем понятен.

Comment: Не нужно в 2016 году предлагать использовать устаревшее расширение `mysql_`